# acts_as_list wipes out parent model's virtual attribute when calling destroy on child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I have a Parent model which has_many children and also a virtual attribute:

```
attr_accessor :new_assocation_model
has_many :children, -> { order("position ASC") }, autosave: true, inverse_of: :parent
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, allow_destroy: true
```

Here is the Child model:

```
belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :children
acts_as_list scope: :parent
```

When the child is destroyed through an update_attributes in the parent, we lose the data assigned to the virtual attribute on the parent.  If I comment out `acts_as_list scope: :parent`, the data assigned to my virtual attribute is preserved.

Is there a way we can preserve the data assigned to the virtual attribute?